# When finding eigenvectors, what is the difference between (A−λI) and (λI-A)?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Take the matrix  \begin{bmatrix}  1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}

If I try to find det(A−λI), I get the determinant of the matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}  1-\lambda &0\\0&1-\lambda\end{bmatrix}

I get that the determinant is (1-λ)(1-λ) = $\lambda^2-2\lambda+1$

But if I were to find det(λI-A), then I get the determinant of the matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}  \lambda-1 &0\\0&\lambda-1\end{bmatrix}

I get that the determinant is (λ-1)(λ-1) = $\lambda^2-2\lambda+1$

Is there ever a case when the two determinants are different?

Comment: Try a $3 \times 3$ example.

Comment: The result is the same upto possibly a sign, so you get the same eigenvalues

Comment: Can anyone fully explain the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when the number of columns is odd, the sign will change.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when the number of columns is odd.

Comment: So is there a preferred method? If the signs are different then which way is commonly used universally?

Comment: Could you perhaps add a little more detail?